# foreach Data Not Updateing in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my local server this script works fine. When I upload this script on live it does not work properly.

It inserts only 126 rows of data into the database, but I need to upload at least 500 rows at a time.

```
<?php
include 'database-config.php';
foreach($_POST['classroll'] as $row=>$classroll)
{
    $sclassroll = $classroll; 
    $mark = $_POST['mark'][$row];
    $type = $_POST['rtype'];
    $session = $_POST['rsession'];
    $department = $_POST['rdepartment'];
    $examtype = $_POST['rextype'];
    $examyear = $_POST['rexyear'];
    $examsubject = $_POST['rexmarksubject'];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO exammarks(studnettype, studentsession, studentdepartment, studentclassroll, examtype, examyear, examsubjec, exammarks) VALUES (:studnettype, :studentsession, :studentdepartment, :studentclassroll, :examtype, :examyear, :examsubjec, :exammarks)");

  $stmt->bindParam('studnettype', $type);
  $stmt->bindParam('studentsession', $session);
  $stmt->bindParam('studentdepartment', $department);
  $stmt->bindParam('studentclassroll', $sclassroll);
  $stmt->bindParam('examtype', $examtype);
  $stmt->bindParam('examyear', $examyear);
  $stmt->bindParam('examsubjec', $examsubject);
  $stmt->bindParam('exammarks', $mark);


$stmt->execute();
}
header('Location: ../home.php');
?>
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that there's a MySQL error after the 126th insert?

Comment: can you check if maximum execution time and script time out on your local server is the same with that of your live server?

Comment: You need to increse max execution time Write `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); ` at the top of your page

Comment: `<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
include 'database-config.php';` #after adding this still it's not working ??? whad should i do now ??

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your `exammarks` table definition on your live server contains a unique index that is not present on your local host server. If that were true some of your `INSERT` operations might fail.

The code you showed us doesn't check for errors. Obviously, when your program deals with high value data (such as the results of student examinations) you should check for errors.

Try this instead:

```
if( !$stmt->execute()) {
    print_r( $arr = $stmt->errorInfo() );
}
else {
    /* INSERT statement completed correctly */
}
```